# How to restore animation when UIView reappears?

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7, core-animation

I have a custom `UIView` subclass (ValveStatusView). It is a subview placed in a custom 'UITableViewCell`subclass (ValveCell) . Upon receiving`awakeFromNib`in`ValveStatusView`, I set up a number of sublayers, one of which is animated. The animation setup code looks like this:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(32, 64 + 6)];
    animation.duration = 0.75;
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
[drop addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```

It makes a "drop" image repeatedly fall from a faucet, forever. These cells are embedded in a `UITableView` and then in  a tabbed view. When I navigate to the other tab, and then back, my animation isn't running anymore. I presume when the view stack containing my view's is no longer mapped to the window, it shuts down the animation. Is that a correct assumption? Assuming it is, what's the idiomatic way to get it running again when the view is mapped again?

I looked through the `UIView` methods, but nothing jumped out as the obvious "hook" to get it running again. I admit to skimming through them, not exhaustively reading it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worded the original question poorly apparently. I've tried with edits to clarify the situation. Regardless of `UITableViewCell` containment or not, my desire was to find a solution that was indifferent to that. Encapsulation and all that.

The following code, added to `ValveStatusView` (my subclass of `UIView`).

```
- (void) didMoveToWindow {
    if (self.window != nil) {
        [self startDropAnimation];
    }
}
```

does the trick. `startDropAnimation` is inspired by the refactoring suggested by @Davlat above:

```
- (void)startDropAnimation {
    CALayer* drop = self.activeFaucet.sublayers.firstObject;
    [drop removeAllAnimations];
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(32, 64 + 6)];
    animation.duration = 0.75;
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    [drop addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
}
```

`didMoveToWindow` was the hook I was looking for (I think).

Comment: It doesn't work when scrolling is very fast (UITableView / UICollectionView doesn't remove cells from superveiw before reuse in this case). Only prepareForReuse works in this case, but it breaks encapsulation, because I use animation in cell's subview...

Answer (score 6):

You should have mentioned in your question that the view containing the animated layer is a subclass of UITableViewCell. :) Because, that is actually the cause of your animation being stopped. UITableViewCell removes the animations from its sublayers to avoid unnecessary computations when a cell is removed from tableview for later reuse. To solve your problem you can override the `prepareForReuse` method of your cell and restart your animation there. So you should do something like this:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        // some initial setup here...

        [self addAnimation];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)prepareForReuse {

    [super prepareForReuse];

    [self addAnimation];
}

- (void)addAnimation {

    // remove previous animations
    [drop removeAllAnimations];

    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(32, 64 + 6)];
    animation.duration = 0.75;
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    [drop addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice catch +1. But will that add memory overhead as far as cell reuse management goes? If so, would there be another alternative that you could share? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what memory overhead you are concerned about. But as you can see in `addAnimation`, we remove all previous animations from `drop` layer each time before we add a new animation. Thus, we don't have any junk collected throughout the reuse cycles.

Comment: So is there no way to encapsulate this at the view level? I don't want my custom view to have to be so tied to the environment it's embedded in. I'd just like it to know when it gets reexposed so it can turn itself back on.

Comment: Just to clarify, the subclass doing the animation is NOT a subclass of UITableViewCell. It is a subclass of UIView. Which is embedded as a control (subview) of my own UITableView subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your code in `- (void) viewWillAppear:` method instead of `awakeFromNib`, this way it will be triggered whenever the view is shown.

**EDIT:**

OK, I see now, you can do that by using `NSNotificationCenter`:

In the awakeFromNib of your customCell add an observer:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(startAnimation:)
                                                     name:@"addAnimation"
                                                   object:nil];
    }
```

- in the `startAnimation:` method you will put of course your animation code.
- And in the `viewWillAppear` of your UITableViewController you post the notification to restart the animations.

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
          postNotificationName:@"addAnimation" 
          object:self];
- Somewhere in the CustomCell you must remove the observer, or the cell will never be unloaded.

Comment: My explanation may have been too vague. My custom view is a subview of custom `UITableViewCell` (also subclass), which are created by a `UITableViewController` in the reuse style. So there's a bit of distance between the `UITableViewController` subclass's `@viewWillAppear:` and these. Maybe I need to traverse the view tree (ugh)? Is there no way to encapsulate it to the `UIView` subclass?

Comment: I edited my post, hope I did understand the problem this time.